# how to fetch and show the results randomly with/without loop php

Tags: php, html, mysql, random, mysqli

hello all i am having a site where i need to show random users/ members in this format 
[image: This is the format in which i want the user images]

i want images of the user in the format as above randomely i have more than 9000 members and need to show the random users in this format the design repeat itself by three

i dont know how to use the loop or use the query to show the images in the above format.

my query is like

```
  $getimages=($con,"select image,id,somethingelse from tablename where id !='' order by rand() limit 21"); 
 // i want 21 images to show here 7*3 (the image here repets it self by three)
 while($theimagelink=mysqli_fetch_array($getimages)){
   // i think array_push may help but dont know how to implement..
 }
```

please give me some hints or any llink i am stuck over here .....

numbering of the image can be changed ....
i need all the three things of select query to display image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you want to get all members, and pull them into an array using your preferred method.

`SELECT MemberID,ImageLink,Field4,Etc FROM Members`

Then you can randomly select a MemberID by using array_rand():

```
<?php
$input = array(array('MemberID' => 1, 'ImageLink' => 'someimage.jpg'),array('MemberID' => 2, 'ImageLink' => 'someimage.jpg'),array('MemberID' => 3, 'ImageLink' => 'someimage.jpg'));
$rand_keys = array_rand($input, 2);
var_dump($input[$rand_keys[0]]) . "\n";
var_dump($input[$rand_keys[1]]) . "\n";
?>
```

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php

**To solve your updated question**

```
$getimages=mysqli_query($con,"select image,id,somethingelse from tablename where id !='' order by rand() limit 21"); 
// i want 21 images to show here 7*3 (the image here repets it self by three)
$Results = array();
while($tmp=mysqli_fetch_assoc($getimages)){
    $Results[] = array('image' => $tmp['image'], 'id' => $tmp['id'], 'somethingelse' => $tmp['somethingelse']);
}
var_dump($Results);
```

Then you can just iterate through the array

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($Results); $i++) {
    echo "<img src='" . $Results[$i]['image'] . "' alt=''><br/>"
    echo $Results[$i]['id'] . '<br/>'
    echo $Results[$i]['somethingelse'] . '<br/><br/>'
}
```

Comment: i have them in array as mysqli_fetch_array

Comment: to display images i need id and link of the image... (two variables)

Comment: There you go, I appended a solution for you to reflect the revision to your question

Comment: Using `$Results[] = "string"` will always create a new index for you, and you can use this method on any depth e.g. `$Results['Member'][0]['Images'][] = "someimage.jpg"` :)

Comment: wow you are awesome just one more thing .. how do i print image,id and somethingelse randomeny so to display image like <img src="image/id/somethingelse"/>

Comment: Updated it again for you

Comment: you are awesome ::) great

Comment: no no dear, i think you misunderstood my question i am getting images randomly but but all the images in the divs 1,2,3,4....7 are same i want them to be randomely in the divs 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 i have applied the for loop outside those div

Comment: You always have 21 random images right? you will have to preplace them around by literally echoing out all 21 randomized images, where you think they should be placed.

Comment: I have provided you with the array you require, the layout is up to you :P (psst multiple divs and a bit of css involving float)

Comment: i can not use loop to display images as i my divs are different and non repetative ... where should i put the loop if i put the loop around the the div s same divs will be repeated

Comment: the indexes 0-23 will always remain the same. hmmmm

Comment: You should start a new question with what you have learnt from here, understand that people won't provide you with the exact answer only guide you. Elaborate as much as you can and I'll try and help you on there

Comment: ok thnkx ... i will do it but tomorrow till then i will try to figure out something from my own .. if you get something please reply me till then.... nice  talking to you buddy